# GLFW call to non-static class function in static key_callback

Tags: c++, opengl, input, glfw, static-functions

I have looked around and read a lot about static functions and variables, I have understood that one can not simply call a non-static variable/function in an static function and so on, so my question is how can I solve this problem I'm having with GLFW key_callback.

In GLFW we have this:

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
  if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

and we add this like other window related calls:

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, window_key_callback);
```

But now I want to be able to call another class function if 'space' key is pressed in the key_callback like this:

in .h file I have

```
#include "A.h"

...

private: 
        A *anotherClass;
```

and in .cpp file I have in the constructor

```
anotherClass = new A();
```

and the rest

```
 static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
  if (key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    antoherClass->draw();
}
```

and this anotherClass is not static, I just want to start drawing if space is pressed.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `antherClass` a global variable, there is no other way around this. Usually a callback function should take a user provided data pointer to allow passing outside information in, it appears there is an API deficiency here.

Edit: Turn out you can use [glfwSetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) and [glfwGetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As yngum pointed, you can use  [glfwSetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) and [glfwGetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06) to have access the the void * pointer of your choice.

Here is a simple example for those that pass around like me:

```
int main(void)
{
    t_MyDatas     datas;
    GLFWwindow    *window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
    //[...]
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, (void *)&datas);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, &KeyCallback);
}

void KeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    t_MyDatas *datas;
    datas = (t_MyDatas *)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    //[...]
}
```

The important point to remember is the cast from (void *) then the cast back to the original structure.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class with your (non-static) `keyCallback` method interactivity, then create an instance of your application class and call the keycallback method on the application instance inside of another, static, keycallback function that then get passed to `glfwSetKeyCallback`. Here is an template that I frequently build upon when starting new projects that utilizes this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// obviously create headers with declarations seperate from definitions
// when spanning across multiple files, but for sake of brevity they
// have not been used.

// application.cpp
class Application {
public:
    GLFWwindow *window;

    Application(std::string title) {

      // boilerplate stuff (ie. basic window setup, initialize OpenGL) occurs in abstract class
      glfwInit();
      window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    }
    void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
      // basic window handling
      if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
      {
        std::cout << "exiting..." << std::endl;
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
      }
    }
    // must be overridden in derived class
    virtual void update() = 0;

    void gameLoop() {
      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // update function gets called here
        update();

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
      }
      glfwTerminate();
    }
};

// myapp.cpp
class MyApp : public Application {
public:
    MyApp(std::string title) : Application(title) {
      // my application specific state gets initialized here
    }
    void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        Application::keyCallback(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_SPACE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            // anotherClass.Draw();
            std::cout << "space pressed!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void update() override {
      // player.Update();
      // anotherClass.Draw();
    }
};

 Application* getApplication() {
     return new MyApp("MyApp");
 }

// main.cpp
// extern Application* getApplication();
Application *app;

static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    MyApp* myApp = (MyApp*)app;
    myApp->keyCallback(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
}

int main() {
    app = getApplication();
    glfwSetKeyCallback(app->window, keyCallback);
    app->gameLoop();
}
```